# How to store a react state into local storage?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, local-storage, jsx

I am starting to learn React and created a todo application which I want to store tasks state into local storage. How can I do that? Here is my code:

Tasks.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AddTask from './AddTask';
import Task from './Task';

class Tasks extends Component {
    state = {
        tasks:[
          {
            task:'Learn web development'
          },
          {
            task:'Learn mobile app development'
          }
        ]
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        localStorage.tasks = JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks);
      }

      addTask = (newTask) => {
        let tasks = [...this.state.tasks, newTask];
        this.setState({
            tasks:tasks
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="tasks">
            <AddTask addTask={this.addTask}/>
            <Task tasks={this.state.tasks}/>
          </div>
     );
  }
}

export default Tasks;
```

AddTask.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddTask extends Component {
    state = {
        task:''
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
         this.setState({task:e.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(this.state.task!=='') {
            this.props.addTask(this.state);
        }

        this.setState({
            task:''
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What should I do?" className="textbox" autoComplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.task} autoFocus/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTask;
```

Task.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Task = ({tasks}) => {
    let task = tasks.map(task => {
        return (
            <li key={task.task}><input type="checkbox"/>{task.task}</li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <ul>
            {task}
        </ul>
    )
}
export default Task;
```

This is working but I wanted to maintain the state after adding a new one even after reloading the page. Hence, I wanted it to store in local storage. A database is a solution but I only wanted it to store locally and not using a DB. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new task you can set it in localStorage like that

```
localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks) + ',');
```

and in the state of your Tasks.js component you get the tasks and split them by comma so you get an array.

```
state = {
   tasks: localStorage.getItem('tasks').split(',')
{
```